# Cannot add custom device in Mobile Browser Simulator (MFP 7.0)

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I tried adding a custom device to MBS using Studio component (as specified [here](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/wl_studio_tools/topics/ttestwl.html)) but the device does not appear in the Add Device list.

Tried to restart the MF Dev Server or Eclipse + clear workspace... no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot get it to work as well. Looks like a defect.

To have this fixed you will need to open an IBM PMR (support ticket), as I see no local workaround for you to do to get it to work.